# jCycle Gallery Not displaying in IE7

Tags: jquery, jcycle

I'm using the jCycle plugin which works in all browsers but in IE7 the pager doesn't display?

It's fine in IE8/9 does anyone have any ideas?

Thank

Jemes

```
    $('.gallery').after('<div id="nav">').cycle({fx: 'fade', speed: 2000, timeout: 2000, pager: '#nav',
        // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<a href="#"></a>'; 
        } 
    }); 



    #nav{margin:0 auto; border:0px solid red; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; padding-top:10px;}
    #nav a{padding:12px; background:url(../images/gallery-circle-outline.png) 0px 6px no-repeat; color:#ccc; cursor:pointer;}
    #nav a.activeSlide, #nav a:hover{background:url(../images/gallery-circle.png) 0px 6px no-repeat;}


<div class="gallery">
    <img src="images/1.png" alt="1" />
    <img src="images/2.png" alt="2" />
    <img src="images/3.png" alt="3" />
    <img src="images/4.png" alt="4" />
    <img src="images/5.png" alt="5" />                
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's due to use of **.after(..)**, try:

```
$('.gallery').after('<div id="nav"></div>').cycle...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response, that didn't work, still no pager in ie7